# In SSIS how can I check if the package or task is being run within BIDS by using the play button or right-clicking and choosing Execute Task?

Tags: ssis, bids

This is not the same as debug mode. I want to display a warning if the developer is actually in BIDS and not display the warning if the package is being run from a scheduled job.

Comment: Your title doesn't seem to match the body of your question.  Assuming your SQL Server uses a service account for package execution, could you check the credentials used for execution?

Comment: BIDS is the same as visual studio. I just want to know if the package is being run within the development tool or not.

Comment: How do you first identify that it's running? Are you observing it in the SSIS service (please clarify)

Comment: You run it by hitting the play button or right-clicking and choosing execute.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid what you are trying to achieve is not possible. BIDS uses the same runtime as your SSIS agent.

You could, however, set an environment variable in your package and remove it during deployment. All of this is hacky and defeats the purpose though.

There really should be no custom logic when running a package locally versus being deployed (other than configurations that might affect the execution graph).

If you are trying to prevent user-error it would be best to educate your peers and/or restrict access.

Comment: We almost had a disaster where a developer accidentally blew away production because he was not aware he was looking at production. If I can add a warning that says - are you sure? This is Production - that's what I'm trying to achieve without doing something hacky like looking for the existence of a file or something.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible. We had similar issues at one of my previous companies. This is an ongoing issue. I am a strong proponent of limiting access to certain, well-trained individuals for production deploys. Also, releases should be accompanied by a formal release process. None of this helps you in your case, I understand. However, let me tell you that I feel your pain and went through the same thing until we had a mature, repeatable release process. :/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a script task that opens a `MsgBox`.   The `MsgBox` would only open when the task is running in BIDS, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: yeah that was my first thought but there doesn't seem to be code to detect if you are in visual studio or not. You can detect if you're in debug mode quite easily but that's not what I want.

Comment: Isn't it the case that the MsgBox will appear if you are running the package in Visual Studio regardless if it's in debug mode?

Comment: Yes but the msgbox will also appear when we deploy the package and run it via a scheduled job. That would stop the package from executing.

Comment: Are you sure about that?  My understanding and experience has been that MsgBoxes are ignored when the package is run by a job.

Comment: Really? I will try that and report back.

Answer (score 0):

I have found but not checked that there is a system variable "System::InteractiveMode" that may be used for this.  Something to check.

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft's documentation on [System Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-variables?view=sql-server-ver15) the InteractiveMode variable should be able to fulfil your need to determine if the package is running from BIDS or from a SQL Job.

> **InteractiveMode (Boolean)**
>   Indicates whether the package is run in
>   interactive mode. If a package **is running in SSIS Designer**, this
>   property is set to **True**. If a package **is running using the DTExec**
>   command prompt utility, the property is set to **False**.

I created a Script task at the beginning of my Flow (in the control flow tab) with a precedence constraint on the following task.  I defined System::InteractiveMode in the ReadOnlyVariables field and used the code below to display the question and process the answer.

```
public void Main()
        {
            if ((bool)Dts.Variables["InteractiveMode"].Value)
            {
                DialogResult button = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to run the package?", "Validate", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

                if (button == DialogResult.No)
                {
                    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
                    return;
                }
            }
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
```

It doesn't stop the execution like the stop button in BIDS but prevents the execution of the rest of the package.  I tried to use the [RunningPackage.Stop()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.runningpackage.stop?view=sqlserver-2019) method but in order to get the list of RunningPackages it requires to be running from SQL Server Integration Service.

I tested it from BIDS and from SQL Server integration service and it worked as expected.